# How to make a PUT API with multiple informations (gin gonic)

Tags: go

I'm using gin-gonic to make a simple API and I would like to create a PUT route to update some user data.
How can i update Andy's age? without changing his Weight for example.

```
type Person struct {
    Name         string `json:"Name"`
    Age          int16  `json:"Age"`
    Weight       int16  `json:"Weight"`
}
```

```
person.PUT("/:name", controllers.PutPersonElement)
```

```
func PutPersonElement(c *gin.Context) {
    name := c.Param("name")

    var params serializer.Person
    if err := c.ShouldBindJSON(&params); err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
        return
    }

    p := serializer.Person{Name: "Andy", Age: 40, Weight: 80}

    p.Name   = params.Name 
    p.Age    = params.Age    // this will be ok
    p.Weight = params.Weight // this will change Andy's weight to 0
}
```

Here is the curl command

```
curl -XPUT -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{"Age": 41}' 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/andy'
```

Comment: Question: how would someone actually modify the weight to 0?

Comment: So my suggestion is to use `Weight       *int16` instead, this way if its a non-null value you can add it to p.Weight.

Comment: @KarthikNayak Thank you, using a pointer is the good solution for my case !

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to the JSON *after* you've already got the initial object.

```
func PutPersonElement(c *gin.Context) {
    p := serializer.Person{Name: "Andy", Age: 40, Weight: 80}

    if err := c.ShouldBindJSON(&params); err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
        return
    }

    // only the fields provided in the JSON should be updated on p
}
```

If your identifier is within the JSON (`id` in the JSON instead of the URL, for example), you could use pointers to only change what's provided.

```
func PutPersonElement(c *gin.Context) {
    var model struct {
        Name string
        Age **int16 // as an example, you'd use a double pointer if your field is nullable
        Weight *int16
    }

    if err := c.ShouldBindJSON(&model); err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
        return
    }

    p := personByName(model.Name)
    if model.Age != nil {
        p.Age = *model.Age
    }
    if model.Weight != nil {
        p.Weight = *model.Weight
    }
}
```